# Upload multiple images with croppie-js

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have resized the images using the croppie-js which output the images in blob/base64 format in the client side.

What is the better way to accomplish this?

I have tried to upload the base64 format but for validating it (size, format etc) I need to write the all basic functionality which creates a lot of code.

Also, Can we create an image on local and attach to the input file so that it will work in a flow?

Comment: Your subject and description doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to write an Ajax post request sending the base64 as a blob to your backend once you get the cropped image